# How to get partcular td in tr in jqGrid?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have tr by this `$('#' + rowid)`

and all tds by this `$('#' + rowid).find("td")`

but how to find a single td? not all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using `getCell('row_id', 'column_index')` method.

See documentation [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3amethods)

[EDIT]

By native Javascript;

```
    var row = document.getElementById('row_id');
    var cell = row.cells[cell_index]; //cell_index will be integer starting with 0 

    /* 
      do whatever you want with cell
    */
```

Comment: It gets me the cell not the td. I need the td so that I can apply my style there.

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't work. I need the td. so that I can apply my style in the td.

Like we do in `$('#' + rowid).find("td"),css(MYStyling)` I want that for particular td.

Comment: you shuold post your table markup. Also, when using native js code, you cannot use `.css()` method. Instead try with `cell.style.[css_property] = 'value'` method.

Comment: Thank you very much and sorry for this silly mistake. by the way you need to put single quote around row_id.

Comment: @soham. Doesn't matter, there is a single or double quotes. The `getElementById()` function is meant to take a string value, so it is ok to use double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
.children(':first')
```

OR

```
index()
```

OR

```
find("td :first")
```